# Need help recreating an image with div tags

Tags: html, css

```css
#box1 {
    background-color: black;
    float: top;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
 
#box2 {
    background-color: red;
    float: top;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
 
#box3 {
    background-color: #807880;
    float: top;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
 
#box4 {
    background-color: silver;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
 
#box5 {
    background-color: purple;
    float: top;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
 
#box6 {
    background-color: #28807d;
    float: top;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
 
#box7 {
    background-color: #198003;
    float: top;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
<div id="box4"></div>
<div id="box5"></div>
<div id="box6"></div>
<div id="box7"></div>
```

I need to create this piece of art in HTML and I'm only allowed to use HTML  and CSS.

How can I recreate this picture in HTML?

[image]

This is what I've tried so far:

```
[1] https://pastebin.com/9h3nyrEj
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. Please show us what have you attempted so far. Thanks !

Comment: skooby... as Francis said try yourself ...even if it takes you a week!  You can do it !

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @skooby, first of all you can google your problem. What I would recommend you: Go on w3schools and learn the `html` and `css` basics. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Francisaskquestion I've been trying a few days now without asking help haha.

Comment: Then can you kindly show us what you tried? We will start helping you there. And also don't use images, please add the codes that result to that

Comment: Good, now we can help what you started there.

Comment: @skooby I've added your pastebin into the live example snippet for your question. Is this what it should look like, or did that external stylesheet come into play?

Comment: Have you read about `flex-box` or `grid`. Because creating that output when your still a beginner will be quite tricky

Comment: I haven't tried a flex-box or grid because my teacher has told that I'm only allowed to use <div> tags. But I'm open for anything that will get me to learn how to make this

Comment: you will only use `<div>` tags, it's a kind of style. But I think grid will be a better solution to your problem, here a link to help you understand https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna read it and try to implement this in my current code.

Comment: @symlink Yeah it's alright I guess, the top box is my CSS code and the rest is HTML. Thanks :D

Comment: Good to hear that. Also if you found a problem don't hesitate to ask, just follow the rules in asking question.

Comment: Have you tried the bootstrap Grid feature? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: No, this is like the 3rd time touching me HTML, and they want me to make this it's very difficult for me.

Comment: OK skooby, i will write you an example. Give me a moment.

Comment: It's a shame you can't use <table> ; https://github.com/hagronnestad/png2table

Answer (score 0):

As you noted this is like the 3rd time touching HTML, I will explain you what to do step by step. But it will require some time to achieve your goal. I could simply paste the results, but this way you will not learn how to use it. You learn by DOING! Of course, when you are stuck; whole stackoverflow wants to help you!

Just to be sure; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/about/license/ Bootstrap is 'Freely download and use Bootstrap, in whole or in part, for personal, private, company internal, or commercial purposes'.

**Step 1:**
Read and study the Introduction of Bootstrap. You will probably forget atleast 90% from everything you read, but that is okay. It's just to give you a head-up on the use of Bootstrap. While using bootstrap you will learn how to implement every feature and more important how to use it.: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

**Step 2:**
Create a file called `index.html` in your root.

**Step 3:** 
Within `index.html` make sure you include bootstrap, just like step 1 which is the very first you read. 'Quick start' -> 'CSS' -> 'JS'. Or just copy & paste the 'Starter template'.

**Step 4:** 
Read this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/ and from here on goodluck! :-). It is quite easy once you've done this part. Look into the different examples Bootstrap provide and design your own layout.

Really, this is all you need to get what you need.

Honestly, I am curious about your results. Do you mind to tag me or give a comment once you're done? :-)

---

Bootstrap is one of the most used frameworks now a days. Many website's use it, thousands (maybe more?) templates which can be downloaded or purchased are based on bootstrap. For example: https://themes.getbootstrap.com/. Personally I love using Bootstrap for my websites.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Best regards

Comment: Thank you for the in dept guide but I'm not using JavaScript here

Comment: You do not have to use JavaScript at all. Give it a try ;-)!

Comment: Example of using Divs only: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_examples5&stacked=h

Comment: or: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_examples6&stacked=h